# Custom Connector for AWS Glue Studio for MS SQL Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm evaluating how to set up our data lake in AWS. Currently got connectivity with Glue Connections in the "old" Glue console, but since we have no glue-legacy I would think adopting the newest tools and practices now would save us converting later.

I am however at a loss of understanding how one creates a simple JDBC connection for an on prem (not AWS RDS) SQL Server. This is as simple as a jdbc-connectionstring in "old Glue", but in Glue Studio you have to either buy a container-based third party connector for $250/mo or roll your own in the form of a jar-file, which isn't exactly a simple step-by-step process.

I can't seem to find any information other that the official aws docs. Is this too new and unfinished a
service? Are AWS pushing people to use DMS to and AWS RDS to be able to do this? (unlikely)

Should I just ignore Glue Studio until it has matured? What am I missing?

PS: I'm sorry for the non-spesific and non-technical art of the question.

Comment: WHy are you using GLUE over an AWS Lambda function?

Comment: @smac2020 - I'm not. Just using the AWS Console.

Comment: I just noticed you are using on prem. However, if you were using an RDS in the cloud and wanted to write serverless logic that performs CRUD operations on an RDS instance, i would recommend looking at Lambda